# in R Sorting by absolute value without changing the data

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to sort data based on the absolute value of one numeric column, without changing any row-wise associations.

I have this data:

```
name <- NULL; value <- NULL
for (i in 1:7) {
  name[i] <- paste0("var", i)
  value[i] <- 4 - i 
}

df <- data.frame(name, value = sample(value,size = 7)); df #set.seed(1)

  name value
1 var1     2
2 var2     1
3 var3    -2
4 var4     0
5 var5     3
6 var6    -3
7 var7    -1
```

## Expected output:

```
df.sorted
  name value
1 var5     3
2 var6    -3
3 var1     2
4 var3    -2
5 var2     1
6 var7    -1
7 var4     0
```

I have tried several methods using `setorderv` and `sort` but I can't figure out how to extend the sorting of the `value` column (by absolute value) to then reorder the `name` column accordingly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `base`:

```
df[sort(abs(df$value),decreasing=T,index.return=T)[[2]],]
  name value
5 var5     3
6 var6    -3
1 var1     2
3 var3    -2
2 var2     1
7 var7    -1
4 var4     0
```

If you're open to using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
   arrange(desc(abs(value)))
  name value
1 var5     3
2 var6    -3
3 var1     2
4 var3    -2
5 var2     1
6 var7    -1
7 var4     0
```

Answer (score 6):

Create an ordering vector and order `df` by that.  No packages are used.

```
o <- order(abs(df$value), decreasing = TRUE)
df[o, ]
```

giving:

```
  name value
5 var5     3
6 var6    -3
1 var1     2
3 var3    -2
2 var2     1
7 var7    -1
4 var4     0
```

### Note

If within multiple rows having the same `abs(value)` you want to order them in decreasing order of `value` use this for `o`:

```
o <- order(abs(df$value), df$value, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: You probably need to add `df$value` in `order` after the `abs` to have the positive values first like OP's output.

Comment: Could there be a way to achieve the same with `sort`?

Comment: Yes, but he has the positive 3 before the negative 3, and it may not consistently do it for your answer (if the row happens to be above it will).Try it with `set.seed(3)`

Comment: Much appreciated!!

Comment: @Andrew that is a good point--I'm not sure how R handles equivalent absolute values when sorting if one is positive and the other negative, so I just guessed when I manually sorted the above. Ordering within values of the same abs value was not necessary for my purposes

Comment: @Dij No worries, R will retain the row ordering if they have the same absolute value. I just wasn't sure whether you did that on purpose. Good luck!!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, when I ran your code it did not match the output. I was just trying to be helpful. But your solution works perfect for OP, all that matters :)

Comment: OK. See added Note.