# R: reordering columns based on order of different column

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x  y   id
1  2      
2  2    1
3  4    
5  6    2
3  4  
2  1    3
```

The blanks in column id should have the same values as the next id value. Meaning my data should actually look like this:

```
x  y   id
1  2    1  
2  2    1
3  4    2
5  6    2
3  4    3
2  1    3
```

I also have a list:

```
list[[1]] = 1 3 2
```

Or alternatively a column:

```
c(1,3,2) = 1, 3, 2
```

Now I would like to reorder my data based on column id accroding to the order in the list. My data should like this then:

```
x  y   id
1  2   1   
2  2   1 
3  4   3
2  1   3
3  4   2
5  6   2
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

EDIT: I don't think it is a duplicate of [in R Sorting by absolute value without changing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154073/in-r-sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data) because I do no want to sort by absolute value but by specific order that is given in a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in R Sorting by absolute value without changing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154073/in-r-sorting-by-absolute-value-without-changing-the-data)

Comment: explain, please.

Comment: I agree with JjBlevins in that this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of the post @Dij links to. The question is not clear to me however; what happens to the rows that have a blank `id` (and are they really blank or `NA`)? Are they unaffected by the sorting? I also don't understand the structure of your `list`; is it a `list` with a single element consisting of the vector `c(1, 3, 2)`? Or is it a `list` with three elements? Best to share data with `dput` to avoid these kind of ambiguities.

Comment: Edited according to you reccomendations Maurits Evers.

Comment: @JjBlevins I think the solution there may be useful, but I also see on closer inspection you don't want the final order to be in ascending or descending order, so a better solution probably exists.

Answer (score 3):

A `base R` option would be  (assuming that the blanks in 'id' column is `NA`)

```
i1 <- !is.na(df1$id)
df1[i1,][match(df1$id[i1], list[[1]]),] <- df1[i1, ]
df1
#  x y id
#1 1 2 NA
#2 2 2  1
#3 3 4 NA
#4 2 1  3
#5 3 4 NA
#6 5 6  2
```

If we need to change the `NA` to succeeding non-NA element

```
library(zoo)
df1$id <- na.locf(df1$id, fromLast = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L), y = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 
 6L, 4L, 1L), id = c(NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: When I change the NA to succeeding non-NA element does the first code still hold?

Comment: I get the following error in my data set: Error in x[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts  any idea what might cause it?

Comment: @JjBlevins  Not clear about the error.  If you can dput a small example that gives the error, it would be helpful